# Is there a way to connect ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC in Linux on machine with only mini dp and usb 3.0 ports?

Tags: multiple-monitors, asus, usb-c

I have been looking for an adapter mini-dp to type c but could not find any (just the other way around)

So in the end I tried my high quality usb to type c cable with my MB16AC monitor and unfortunately I'm getting

> You device is not using usb alt mode. please try to install the latest dirvers

Note: I've installed latest displaylink drivers from Asus website and restarted my machine (for Linux 64bit)

Computer model: Dell Precision 7510

Comment: Strange... According to https://www.asus.com/displays-desktops/monitors/zenscreen/zenscreen-mb16ac/ USB-A is supported. On the other hand a driver for Linux is not available for download. Perhaps https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/ would work?

Answer (score 1):

> I have been looking for an adapter mini-dp to type c but could not find any (just the other way around)

Even if such cables exist, and they likely do somewhere, you will still have the problem of getting power to the display.  It appears from the product description I found ( https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/MB16AC/overview/ ) the only way to get power into the display is with the USB-C port.  A mini-DP to USB-C/DP cable is unlikely to provide any power to the USB-C port.  Something that can take a DisplayPort video stream and power and put that onto a USB-C cable is not likely to be cheap.

> So in the end I tried my high quality usb to type c cable with my MB16AC monitor

A quality USB-A to USB-C cable should have the stylized "SS" symbol, USB trident, and the number 10 showing on the connector.  The USB trident shows it meets the USB spec, the "SS" and number 10 means it's rated for 10 Gbps.  If your cable does not have this then that might be why it's not working.

> Note: I've installed latest displaylink drivers from Asus website and restarted my machine (for Linux 64bit)

Then perhaps you need to seek more assistance from ASUS on this.  My best guess is that the cable is not as "quality" as it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a long time after, but for others that might be looking into this. A usb A to C cable would not be able to deliver the dp alt mode, because the alt(ernative) usage of the usb standard is only defined for usbc and not compatible with usb a, even with high enough bandwidth. If you have a usbc only external screen, your only option is to have a properly supported device with usbc dp alt mode, that delivers power and dp signal. A dongle/adapter from others might exist (have at least seen one from hdmi to usbc with power) but those are expensive because they have to actively adapt the signals.